# Google Shows my website title and links in other website's adwords

Tags: google-ads

Today while searching my domain name in google search i found the first link is google adwords link with my website title and link as subdomain.

> Eg .I searched  mydomain.com in google search
>
> first google adwords result
>
> **mydomain.com** buy best products from **www.theirdomain.com/mydomain** , **mydomain.theirdomain.com**

What i feel is this the way of hijacking my domain traffics to their domain ?
Can i complaint to google adwords about this about policy issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely allowed within AdWords **unless** they are mentioning a trademarked term or brand name of yours in their ad copy. [AdWords trademark policy](https://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/answer/6118?hl=en-GB). Although this year, Google did [release a new policy](http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/03/22/starting-april-23-google-will-allow-trademarks-as-keywords-in-adwords-worldwide/) that allowed advertisers to **bid on** trademarked terms for the first time.

In fact, it is quite common to bid on and use competitor's name/products in AdWords ads.

You can learn more on this [here](http://certifiedknowledge.org/blog/qa-should-you-bid-on-your-competitors-name-or-use-their-name-in-ad-copy/).